# Multiple definition of string array

Tags: c

I want to create a const array with some error message in it. But when I try to compile my code, I have this error :

```
multiple definition of `DDP_errList'; main.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I have defined my array one time inside an #ifndef so really don't understand why.

So, I have testArray.h

```c
#ifndef testArray
#define testArray

extern int DDP_Errno;

const char * DDP_errList[] = {
    "err1",
    "err2"
};

void DDP_perror(char* msg);

int test();

#endif
```

testArray.c

```c
#include "DDP.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int DDP_Errno=-1;

int test(){
    DDP_Errno = 0;
    return -1;
}

void DDP_perror(char * data){
    if(DDP_Errno>=0 && DDP_Errno<=2){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : %s\n", data, DDP_errList[DDP_Errno]);
    else{
        fprintf(stderr,"%s : Success\n",data);
    }
}
```

main.c

```c
#include "DDP.h"

int main(){
    test();
    DDP_perror("test");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove definition of DDP_errList from the header

Comment: @tstanisl There is no way to keep it inside ?

Comment: Remove it from the header and put it in `testArray.c` instead.  In the header, replace it with `extern const char * DDP_errList[];`.

Comment: @MrSolarius, the specifics of the type involved are irrelevant.  But if you like, you can find a lot of other answers here on SO that say the same thing with different particulars.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks, that works! It's not perfect because I can't define in header, but I have a line to comment with the content of my definition.